# tput cup in python on the commandline

Tags: python, printing, terminal

Is there an elegant solution to do this shell script in Python without importing os ?

```
    tput cup 14 15; echo -ne "\033[1;32mtest\033[0m" ; tput cup 50 0
```

This just has been gnawing in my mind for some time now :)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the terminfo capabilities are accessible via [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). Initialize it and use [`curses.tiget*()`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.tigetflag) to get the capabilities you care about.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for your input, it was a great push in the right direction.
In the end i came up with this little code that will help me conquer the world :)

```
from curses import *
setupterm()

#cols = tigetnum("cols")
#lines = tigetnum("lines")
#print str(cols) + "x" + str(lines)

place_begin = tparm(tigetstr("cup"), 15, 14)
place_end = tparm(tigetstr("cup"), 50, 0)

print place_begin + "-- some text --" + place_end
```

@TZ.TZIOY, thanks, i think using stdout rather than using print indeed is a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Given that

- you assume ANSI escape sequences
- `tput cup 14 15 | cat -v` displays `^[[15;16H`

the whole suggested script results in the following Python script:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\033[15;16H\033[1;32mtest\033[m\033[51;1H")
# and a possible sys.stdout.flush() here, depending on your needs
```