# Delete several lines in IPython console

Tags: python, spyder

I'm quite new to Pyhton, I use it since September in Spyder (Python 3.4). and I would like to create a program that solves a sudoku grid and displays it (in IPython console) during its completion.
I hopefully did successfully the sudoku solver and I get a printable grid in output (I only post the printable grid code):

```
def sudoku_pp(g):
    c = g.replace("0","_")
    s = ""
    l = 0
    for i in range(13):
        if i % 4 == 0:
            for _ in range(25):
                s += "-"        
        else:
            k = 9*l 
            s += "|"           
            for j in range(9):
                s += " "+c[k+j]
                if j%3 == 2:
                    s += " |"
            l += 1
        s += "\n"
    return(s)
```

where g is a string containing every number line to line, e.g. `SUD1 = '530070000600195000098000060800060003400803001700020006060000280000419005000080079'` and

```
>>>print(sudoku_pp(SUD1))
-------------------------
| 5 3 _ | _ 7 _ | _ _ _ |
| 6 _ _ | 1 9 5 | _ _ _ |
| _ 9 8 | _ _ _ | _ 6 _ |
-------------------------
| 8 _ _ | _ 6 _ | _ _ 3 |
| 4 _ _ | 8 _ 3 | _ _ 1 |
| 7 _ _ | _ 2 _ | _ _ 6 |
-------------------------
| _ 6 _ | _ _ _ | 2 8 _ |
| _ _ _ | 4 1 9 | _ _ 5 |
| _ _ _ | _ 8 _ | _ 7 9 |
-------------------------
```

My sudoku solver prints a full grid each step, how to erase it entirely and rewrite another one on it?

Thanks a lot and sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you would simply have to use `tput`, but I know no equivalent to this tool in Python. However, you can still print the escape codes that would do the job.

The `tput` command for moving the cursor to the previous line and erasing it is, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745408/4352108):

```
tput cuu1
tput el
```

Which translates in term of escape codes into `\033[K\033[A`.

So basically, you’d just have to do this 13 times based on your example to erase the full sudoku:

```
print(13 * "\033[K\033[A")
print(sudoku_pp(SUD1))
```

I have only tested this solution in a iPython terminal in Linux, but not in Spyder itself, let me know if it works.

EDIT: Also note this answer about [using `curses`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212096/4352108).

Comment: sorry, that didn't work, and in fact it added one more blank line between grids :( Don't go too much trouble.

Comment: @Maxence1402, what platform are you working with (Windows, *nix, etc.)? I might be able to test the solution further if you give me more details on this. Also, you should consider using [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html).

Comment: I use Windows 10, 64 bits, and Spyder 2.7, Python 3.4. I tried once using curses but I only were able to rewrite the last line..

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your print statement:

```
print(sudoku_pp(SUD1), flush=True, end='\r')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it only deletes last line, I'm currently writing 13 lines + 1 line for CR so i'm still writing 13 lines with '\r' and putting '\r'*13 does not work...

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. Sorry about that. Why not just insert a sys.stdout.flush() call?